# Fine Uploader and i18n

Tags: internationalization, fine-uploader

while most strings which fineuploader sends to end users (not the developer fixing bugs in embedding fine uploader) come from the template, and are hereby easily translateable on the serverside creating that template, I've found some places which don't seem to have this origin?

the place which came to me during using:

```
confirmMessage: "Are you sure you want to delete {filename}?",
```

a couple of other strings can be found when grepping through fineuploader-4.2.1.js:

```
qq.status = {
SUBMITTING: "submitting",
SUBMITTED: "submitted",
REJECTED: "rejected",
QUEUED: "queued",
CANCELED: "canceled",
PAUSED: "paused",
UPLOADING: "uploading",
UPLOAD_RETRYING: "retrying upload",
UPLOAD_SUCCESSFUL: "upload successful",
UPLOAD_FAILED: "upload failed",
DELETE_FAILED: "delete failed",
DELETING: "deleting",
DELETED: "deleted"
                return new qq.Promise().failure(imgOrCanvas, "File or URL not found.");
                "due to CORS on a user agent that does not support pre-flighting.", "warn");
                this._options.callbacks.onError(id, name, "Delete request failed", xhrOrXdr);
                this._options.callbacks.onError(id, name, "Delete request failed with response code " + xhrOrXdr.status, xhrOrXdr);
                this._options.callbacks.onError(id, name, "XHR returned response code " + xhr.status, xhr);
            typeError: "{file} has an invalid extension. Valid extension(s): {extensions}.",
            sizeError: "{file} is too large, maximum file size is {sizeLimit}.",
            minSizeError: "{file} is too small, minimum file size is {minSizeLimit}.",
            emptyError: "{file} is empty, please select files again without it.",
            noFilesError: "No files to upload.",
            tooManyItemsError: "Too many items ({netItems}) would be uploaded.  Item limit is {itemLimit}.",
            maxHeightImageError: "Image is too tall.",
            maxWidthImageError: "Image is too wide.",
            minHeightImageError: "Image is not tall enough.",
            minWidthImageError: "Image is not wide enough.",
            retryFailTooManyItems: "Retry failed - you have reached your file limit.",
            onLeave: "The files are being uploaded, if you leave now the upload will be canceled."
        responseProperty: "error",
        tooManyFilesError: "You may only drop one file",
        unsupportedBrowser: "Unrecoverable error - this browser does not permit file uploading of any kind."
        autoRetryNote: "Retrying {retryNum}/{maxAuto}..."
        confirmMessage: "Are you sure you want to delete {filename}?",
        deletingStatusText: "Deleting...",
        deletingFailedText: "Delete failed"
        namePromptMessage: "Please name this image"
            throw new Error("file with passed id was not added, or already uploaded or canceled");
        promise.failure(img, "Problem drawing thumbnail!");
            drawPreview.failure(container, "Browser cannot render image!");
            drawPreview.failure(container, "Not previewable");
            thePromise.failure("No EXIF header to be found!");
```

did I miss something in the documentation here?
THIA - Cheers, 
 Willi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confirm message you mentioned above can be changed in the Fine Uploader UI mode [`deleteFile` options](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#deleteFile).

Many of the other items listed in your question are easily customizable via options defined in the documentation.  For example, see the [core `messages` option](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#messages) and the additional [`messages` option for UI mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options-ui.html#messages).  Also, a number of the items listed above are not messages at all, and/or are not passed along directly to the user, such as `responseProperty`, all of the `qq.status` items, etc.  If there are specific text items that you must override but either cannot due to an oversight in the library, please open up a feature request.

Comment: ah, great; most probably the {filename} will work then too? The current citadel release will have to live without them being translateable, I'll change that now.

Comment: {filename} will be replaced by Fine Uploader with the name of the actual file.

Comment: Are these swapped in the documentation? their name would imply that for me...
   deletingFailedText

   The status message to appear next to a file that is pending deletion.

   deletingStatusText

   The status message to appear next to a file that has failed to delete.

Comment: @dothebart, Good eye! Fixed.